# Adding status of files in power Bi dashboard

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-approval, powerbi, dashboard

I have a document library with document status as pending, approved, rejected.
I want to show status of document in power BI. But column fields are not visible.
[image]
What must be the connector I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

The “Approval Status” column is the default column in SharePoint, then you could create a custom column in the library. Then set the value of the custom column as the value of the “Approval Status” column.

updated：

Sorry for giving your confusion.

The “Approval Status” column is a lookup field and not applicable in the calculated fields.

Then we can use SharePoint designer workflow to set the value of the custom column as the value of the “Approval Status” column.

Because the “Approval Status” column is the lookup column, we cannot get the string value of the “Approval Status” column, we only can get the number of the “Approval Status” column.

Comment: But that column need to be updated manually?

Comment: you could create a calculated column, and set the value of the column equal to the value of the “Approval Status” column. then you do not need to update the custom column manually.

Comment: Its showing me technical error, can u tell me exact formula?

Comment: One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.- this is the error

Comment: I have updated my reply.

Comment: But, I don't have access to SP designer, Flow, Power Apps... :(

Answer (score 0):

You will find Content Approval Status & Commnets hidden in

[image]